# mysql - Find duplicate users with firstname/lastname swapped

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I need to find users that have been inserted twice in a table, but with their first name & last name swapped.

e.g. Bob Smith is in the database as

```
firstname:Bob 
lastname:Smith
&
firstname:Smith
lastname:Bob
```

What's the best query to find those users?

The server runs mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select 
  *
FROM UserTable ut
JOIN UserTable ut2 on ut2.firstname = ut.lastname and ut2.lastname = ut.firstname
```

Comment: That works well with "ut.user_id, ut.firstname, ut.lastname, ut2.user_id, ut2.firstname, ut2.lastname" instead of * (bit more reduced set of data) and also "order by ut2.firstname, ut2.lastname" at the end

Comment: @Ben you were not specific about the data you wanted returned.  You many want to update your question.

Comment: No pressure, i'm just adding some feedback

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    firstname, lastname
FROM
    (
    SELECT firstname, lastname FROM MyTable -- WHERE firstname <> lastname
    UNION ALL
    SELECT lastname, firstname FROM MyTable -- WHERE firstname <> lastname
    ) foo
GROUP BY
   firstname, lastname
HAVING 
   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I like this solution.  Nice way to get a single result for each duplicate.

Comment: @john & gbn. Yes, but at the same time I would need to know what the IDs of those records are

Comment: @Ben: you may want to ignore rows where the names are the same. I meant to comment on that. To get IDs, a self join is easier to be honest. It can be done here but it becomes more complex than a self join

Comment: @gbn. Good effort in removing the duplicates but I kinda need those duplicates so I can get the IDs

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT orig.firstname, orig.lastname
FROM yourtable AS orig
INNER JOIN yourtable AS dupes ON orig.firstname = dupe.lastname AND orig.lastname = dupe.firstname
```

Basically, do a self-join on the user table, but only on the records where the fn/ln dupe-swap occurs.